# How see fingerprints visually as images?

Tags: fingerprint

fprint stores fingerprints in /var/lib/fprint/, how can I view these visually as images? I can't find any docs of fprint, except a few short man pages.

Comment: [This RedHat bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1693356) identifies the file format as [ISO/IEC 19794-2](https://www.iso.org/standard/38746.html) format, which is not exactly an image, but a "representation of fingerprints using the fundamental notion of minutiae". So it's more like a list of features to look for and their relative locations, than an actual image.

Comment: Fingerprints are treated like passwords. At initialization time, the True fingerprint (what the sensor says) is put through an encoding/compression/encryption step, storing the resultant value. When a Challenge fingerprint is presented, it is put through the same encoding/compression/encryption step,  and the result is compared with the stored result. The "image of the fingerprint" never exists,  and it's Cryptographicly Hard to reverse the process to get back to the fingerprint sensor data.

Comment: @waltinator do you know that for a fact, or is that how you imagine fingerprint data should be handled?

Comment: @StephenKitt  The ISO document noted above uses terms like "ridge skeleton endpoint" and "valley bifurcation", which implies a significant level of pre-processing. "skeleton" is a "single-pixel-wide representation of a ridge or valley obtained by successive symmetric thinning operations".

Comment: @Paul_Pedant yes, there’s pre-processing, but nothing like that described by waltinator. There’s no cryptographic hashing involved here.

Comment: I once read a description of how the protocol of one particular USB fingerprint reader was reverse-engineered. Apparently there are several ways to implement a fingerprint reader: the cheapest/least secure ones do indeed output basically a black&white or grayscale image and let the host deal with all the processing, better ones will do the processing within the reader. Some may store the authorized fingerprint data internally, and only report back essentially a "match authorized print #X"/"no match" result.

Comment: Libfprint has the [FpImage class](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/libfprint-dev/FpImage.html), described as: "Some devices will provide the image data corresponding to a print; this object allows accessing this data."